# PostgreSQL issue with named arguments in a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

PostgreSQL 8.4 on Linux. I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION production.add_customer (  
name varchar(100),  
email_address varchar(300),  
street_address text,  
city varchar(50),  
state varchar(2),  
zip varchar(10),  
secret1 bytea,  
secret2 bytea,   
secret3 bytea,  
secret4 bytea,  
referrer text)  
RETURNS integer as $$  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO customers (name, email_address, street_address, city, state, zip, secret1, secret2, secret3, secret4, create_date, referrer) VALUES  
(name, email_address, street_address, city, state, zip, create_date, referrer
pgp_sym_encrypt(secret1, 'reallylongrandomstring'),   
pgp_sym_encrypt(secret2, 'reallylongrandomstring'),   
pgp_sym_encrypt(secret3, 'reallylongrandomstring'),   
pgp_sym_encrypt(secret4, 'reallylongrandomstring'),   
current_timestamp, referrer);  
RETURNING customer_id;  
END;  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That is returning this error when I try an create it:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO customers ( $1 ,  $2 ,  $3 ,  $4 ,  $5 ,  $6 ,  ...
                            ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO customers ( $1 ,  $2 ,  $3 ,  $4 ,  $5 ,  $6 ,  $7 ,  $8 ,  $9 ,  $10 , create_date,  $11 ) VALUES ( $1 ,  $2 ,  $3 ,  $4 ,  $5 ,  $6 , create_date,  $11  pgp_sym_encrypt( $7 , 'reallylongrandomstring'), pgp_sym_encrypt( $8 , 'reallylongrandomstring'), pgp_sym_encrypt( $9 , 'reallylongrandomstring'), pgp_sym_encrypt( $10 , 'reallylongrandomstring'), current_timestamp,  $11 )
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "add_customer" near line 8
myserver=#
```

I have tried `ALIAS FOR`, no luck. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arguments have the same name as the columns in the `INSERT`; PL/pgSQL is incorrectly substituting **both** sets of identifiers (columns and values) with the argument, ending up with the nonsensical `INSERT` you see in the error.

See the **Caution** section on [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html) for the official word - but essentially you'll need to change the argument names.

Comment: That fixed my problem. That smells kinda bugish no? Neither Oracle or SQL Server have a problem with that format. Thanks a lot SimonJ!

Comment: I'm not actually sure they consider it a bug, given how much discussion is dedicated to the subject in the docs. If nothing else, it encourages good practice by forcing non-overlapping names!

Comment: Oh, and it's quite possible to get into a similar (but maybe more subtle) mess with Oracle too - I've seen innocent `SELECT` queries suddenly break when someone introduced either a local variable with the same name as a column, or vice versa...

Answer (score 1):

This behavior will be changed in PostgreSQL 9.0.

a) PostgreSQL 9.0 is smarter and applies variables only at the right places

b) priority is optional - like PostgreSQL, like Oracle or raise exception

For older version use prefix for all local variables and parameters in every functions with integrated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL.

Change it to `INSERT INTO customers ("name", etc etc...`

Also what he said: prepend all your variable names with a `_` or similar.